# What does "Do you want to reset the field mapping" mean in QGIS Refactor Fields dialog?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, fields-attributes, vector-layer, field-mapping

I want to convert the type of some fields in a vector layer from String to Real. I am trying to use the **Processing -> QGIS geoalgorithms -> Vector table tools -> Refactor fields** tool to do this. When I open this up and select the layer I'm trying to edit, a dialog pops up that asks "Do you want to reset the field mapping?" (Yes/No) ... I can't find documentation anywhere on what this means.

Can someone explain?

[image]

(See lower center in image for dialog I'm referring to)

Comment: You might have done this *Refactor fields* operation before, and the `Fields mapping` as displayed may, potentially, be coming from your previous job. Or you might have loaded other mapping from the layer next to [Load fields] button. Either case, please do not worry about it. It is not a warning, just asking if you want to refresh the setting.

Comment: Thanks @Joseph Let me borrow your comment which looks more appropriate to describe what it means.

Answer (score 3):

You might have done this Refactor fields operation before, and the *Fields mapping* currently displayed may, potentially, be coming from your previous job. Or you might have loaded other mapping from the layer next to [Load fields] button. Either case, please do not worry about it.

The message window is not a warning, nor error. In this instance, *reset* is another name for *reload* (or *refresh*) ------- with thanks to @Joseph

Comment: I had never used the "Refactor fields" tool before, but I had added some fields via the Field Calculator, so maybe that was it.

Comment: @J.Taylor I see. I have not seen that case. Thanks sharing!